# How to add new custom property to the a web application using powershell script?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, properties

I need to add the custom property to all the rootweb in webapplication using powershell script?
How to do that?

Comment: try read here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33416/activate-feature-in-powershell-and-specify-custom-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
#Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://sp_site..."
$myRootWeb = $spWeb.RootWeb | Add-Member NoteProperty MyProp -Value test -PassThru
$myRootWeb.MyProp
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use New-Object to create new custom objects.

```
$customObject = New-Object -Property @{"Name"="Ravi";"Age"=30} -TypeName PSObject
$customObject

                                                        Age Name
                                                        --- ----
                                                         30 Ravi
```

Or you can extend an existing .NET type using Update-TypeData cmdlet. In PowerShell v2, this requires creating custom ps1xml format files for the type data. 
How to create PS1XML format files: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878339(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

In PowerShell v3, this is much easier. Using the same Update-TypeData cmdlet, you can extend the properties within the session. However, the changes made to the object properties exist only in the current session. You need to use PowerShell profile to make these changes everytime you open the PowerShell console or any other PowerShell host.

Adding Extended types in PowerShell 3.0: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/08/29/pstip-adding-extended-types-the-powershell-3-0-way/

Comment: I think the OP isn't asking about PSCustomObjects but is asking about custom property of sharepoint webapplication (IMO)....

Comment: aah, I misread the question. Thanks! :) I read it as extending the webapplication properties.